# What do you call the walls of a toilet cabin?

Tags: word-request

[image]

I am thinking there must be a word, because the cabin walls are different from regular walls and often they have gap below and above them, and thus are significantly different from a wall, and most of the so-called cabins don't look like cabins, because they have open space below and above them.

Is there a word or a general word that can be used to describe these walls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Toilet Cabins are referred to as **Stalls** and the Doors are simply **Stall Doors**, as far as known, modern stalls do not have Structural Importance and thus do not have names for the structures pieces, they are simply walls or stalls.

They are not technically attached to the walls so you can either refer to it as a **Stall**, **Wall**, **Panel** or **Partition**.

> verb. A Partition: "divide into parts."

I would recommend calling it a Partition.